# Selecting a variable property in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I did a code to search number by number and do something if the number is what i want, the code works, but i trying to select this number with a better way:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# Chromedriver and url
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Gabri\anaconda3\chromedriver.exe")
wait: WebDriverWait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/941078')

# The list of all numbers
maps = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(""".beatmapset-beatmap-picker__beatmap""")

# Loop for clean the string and convert to float
for stars in maps:
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(stars).perform()

    # I found this way to clean and show, is a lot of steps ... but it works =/
    treatment = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.beatmapset-header__star-difficulty').text
    treatment = treatment .replace('Star Difficulty ', '')
    treatment = treatment .replace(',', '.')
    clean = float(treatment )

    # This way this is much more efficient, but I can't make it work
    attempt = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(""".beatmap-icon""").get_property('data-stars')

    # In final, both numbers have to be the same (at least that's how it was supposed to happen)
    print(f'{attempt=}\n{clean=}\n')
```

I already tried `attempt = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(""".beatmap-icon""")[maps.index(stars)].get_property('data-stars')` but returns `None`

The numbers that i trying to select is these:
[image]

Basically, the idea is show each number that appear below:

[image: difficulty number]

But using just the `attempt` variable or something short like this

Someone can help me with this selector?

## FINAL CODE:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Gabri\anaconda3\chromedriver.exe")
wait: WebDriverWait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/941078')
maps = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(""".beatmapset-beatmap-picker__beatmap""")

for stars in maps:
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(stars).perform()

    attempt2 = float(driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//div[contains(@class,'beatmap-icon')])[{maps.index(stars)+1}]").get_attribute('data-stars'))

    print(f'{attempt2=}\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each web element `stars` , you are just looking for first

```
attempt = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(""".beatmap-icon""").get_property('data-stars')
```

attribute. You will have to induce index for attempt as well.

**Code :**

```
# The list of all numbers
maps = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(""".beatmapset-beatmap-picker__beatmap""")

j = 1
# Loop for clean the string and convert to float
for stars in maps:
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(stars).perform()

    # I found this way to clean and show, is a lot of steps ... but it works =/
    treatment = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.beatmapset-header__star-difficulty').text
    treatment = treatment.replace('Star Difficulty ', '')
    treatment = treatment.replace(',', '.')
    try:
        clean = float(treatment )
    except:
        print('could not convert string to float:')
        pass

    # This way this is much more efficient, but I can't make it work
    attempt = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//div[contains(@class,'beatmap-icon')])[{j}]").get_attribute('data-stars')
    j = j + 1
    # In final, both numbers have to be the same (at least that's how it was supposed to happen)
    print(f'{attempt=}\n{clean=}\n')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Output :**

```
attempt='4.96'
clean=4.96

attempt='6.03'
clean=6.03

attempt='6.07'
clean=6.07

attempt='6.33'
clean=6.33

attempt='6.39'
clean=6.39

attempt='6.52'
clean=6.52

attempt='7.14'
clean=7.14
```

Comment: Thanks bro =DDD, i knew that as a error with index but i didn't  identificate where haha.  tks for show me! By the way, the error ```could not convert string to float``` also sometimes appears to me and i still don't know why lol

Comment: I did not debug that part as that was not intended in this answer. You could try to put some sleep so that the element would be rendered properly. `time.sleep(2)` before `treatment = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.beatmapset-header__star-difficulty').text`

Comment: Don't need to worry, u already did so much to me haha. I learned with your index solution and i changed the selector ```attempt...{j}``` to ```attempt...{maps.index(stars)+1}``` and it works (for while XD)